# Как извлечь данные из колонки, содержащей JSON?

Tags: json, excel

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно решить следующую задачу. В Excel есть колонка с данными, в каждой ячейке колонки находится JSON сходной структуры но с разными данными. Необходимо в соседнюю с JSON ячейку извлечь числовые или строчные данные. Ниже пример JSON. Например, нужно извлекать number:

```
{"array": [1, 2, 3],
 "boolean": true,
 "null": null,
 "number": 123,
 "object": {
       "a": "b",
       "c": "d",
       "e": "f"
       },
 "string": "Hello World"
}
```

Comment: *в каждой ячейке колонки находится JSON* Excel даже не подозревает о существовании такого типа данных - он считает, что хранит текстовые данные. И поступайте с ними соответственно как с текстом - используя текстовые функции, извлекайте нужные данные.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ был найден на другом ресурсе. Проблема решается с помщью Power Query. 
первые 2 шага:
1) Именовать область ячеек с JSON. Открыть Power Query и добавить первую запись

```
= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="название_именованной_области"]}[Content]
```

Это позволит забрать значения из всех ячеек именованого диапазона.

2) Далее кликнуть Add custom column. Добавить название новой колонки и формулу:

```
each Json.Document([Column1])
```

где Column1 это  колонка, содержащая JSON.

Дальше можно выполнить Expand или Extract действия, кликая по иконке в заголовках соотв. колонок. В зависимости от структуры JSON и требований к извлекаемой информации, будет отличаться и то, какие колонки/значения необходимо развернуть. Подробнее о вопросе в ветке на форуме [planetaexcel](https://www.planetaexcel.ru/forum/index.php?PAGE_NAME=message&FID=1&TID=107351&TITLE_SEO=107351-kak-izvlech-i-razbit-dannye-iz-yacheyki-s-json-v-sosednie-yacheyki)